# JQuery onclick and focusout

Tags: jquery, onclick

Eu tenho minha navbar com um botão de busca que chama um slideToogle() e exibe um formulário com um input texto dentro abaixo da minha navbar.

Eu quero que meu formulário seja escondido ao perder o foco ou o botão de busca seja clicado de novo.

Então meu problema é esse, quando clico no botão de busca com o form aberto, ele executa a mesma coisa duas vezes.

http://codepen.io/anchietajunior/pen/amxmYX

Comment: Traduza sua pergunta por gentileza, este é o Stack em Português.

Comment: Já foi traduzida.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo parecido com isso companheiro.

---

try something like this.

```
var i = 0;
$('#search_button').on('click', function(e){
    if(i == 0){
      i++;
      e.preventDefault();
      $searchbar.slideToggle(300);
      $('#search_form_input').focus();
   } else {
      i = 0;
      $searchbar.trigger('focusout');
   }
});
```

Comment: Traduza sua resposta por gentileza, este é o Stack em Português.

Comment: Certo @diegofm, irei alterar minha resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou, infelizmente.